# Errors: Undefined variable: retval and undefined constant length - assumed 'length'

Tags: php, undefined

This function works fine if I disable errors. But I have to solve them.
So I enabled the errors and found the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: retval in /home/content/79/9482579/html/gamelinkexchange.com/all/function.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length' in /home/content/79/9482579/html/gamelinkexchange.com/all/function.php on line 55

Here is my function:

```
function time_ago($date,$granularity=2) {
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $date = strtotime($date); 
    $difference = time() - $date;
    $periods = array('decade' => 315360000,
        'year' => 31536000,
        'month' => 2628000,
        'week' => 604800, 
        'day' => 86400,
        'hour' => 3600,
        'minute' => 60,
        'second' => 1);
foreach ($periods as $key => $value) {
        if ($difference >= $value) {
            $time = floor($difference/$value);
            $difference %= $value;
            $retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' '; /*error*/
            $retval .= (($time > 1) ? $key.'s' : $key);
            $granularity--;
        }
        if ($granularity == '0') { break; }
    }
    return $retval.' ago';      
}
function gethours($str)
{
     if(strpos($str, "decade"))
     {
        return 0;
     }
     else if(strpos($str, "year"))
     {
        return 0;
     }
     else if(strpos($str, "month"))
     {
        return 0;
     }
     else if(strpos($str, "week"))
     {
        return 0;
     }
     else if(strpos($str, "day"))
     {
        return 0;
     }
     else if(strpos($str, "hours"))
     {
        $strarr= explode(" ",$str);
        $j=0; /*error*/
        for($i=0;$i<$strarr.length;$i++)
        {
           if($strarr[$i]=="hours")
           { 
                 $j=$i-1;
           }
        }
        return $strarr[$j];
     }
else {   return 1; }
}
```

This function is running very slow so I need to solve these errors. I tried solution provided in other pages of this website and other forums but nothing did help. Please provide a good solution which consumes less resources.
I need a solution to this. Because every entry has to pass time.

This is my first question, I am a newbie, please help. Thank You.

Comment: This really isn't a "do my work for me" site, and this question seems particularly geared to finish your job for you instead of asking a question that would be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't see you initialising your `$retval` anywhere. You should maybe have something like `$retval = ''` before you start appending anything to it, based on its value.

About the other error, you've mistaken **php** with **Java**. In php you get the length of an array with `count($strarr)` instead of `$strarr.length`

**Update**
Instead of

```
$retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';
```

you could simply use

```
$retval = $time.' ';
```

Comment: @Asim Just get rid of `($retval ? ' ' : '')`. It's useless, since `$retval` is not defined at this point at all.

Comment: @Asim Why do you want to use anything in place of it? It doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: if i remove that 20th statement the $retval below in other line causing this error again..

Comment: i tried your solution about 20th line. it does not create any error but it change the logic and showing wrong time.

Comment: If so, are you sure you've pasted all the code in your question? Because the line `$retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';` doesn't make much sense if `$retval` hasn't been defined before that.

Comment: @Asim sorry what is it that you're "not using it"?

Comment: i just use this command to get the above function result.
$beforetime = time_ago($row['createdtime']);
that's it. The result of the above function now shows only seconds and all seconds are random numbers. if i sort them using mysql querry.

Comment: Please help me with new logic because i tried it several times with different logic but result showing wrong time.. This function is just used to calculated difference between posted time and current time.. Please help..

Comment: Well, that's a totally different question then... BTW I also fail to see the logic behind `$difference %= $value;` and the use of it...

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' '; /*error*/
```

To this:

```
$retval .= (isset($retval))? ' ':'';
$retval .= $time.' '; //you shouldn't have the error on that line again -- it's because
//the variable does not exist and you're sing it in a comparison
```

Change this line below:

```
for($i=0;$i<$strarr.length;$i++)
```

To this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($strarr);$i++){....}
//arrays in PHP cannot be used like objects (-> not .)
```

Comment: first error "$retval" error is same as "Undefined variable: retval" please help. thanks to solve my second error.

Comment: for the first error: i totally missed it... it should be `$retval = (isset($retval))? ' ':'';` NOT `$retval .= (isset.......)`

Comment: i tried this changing ".=" to "=" And "isset" Cause change in logic and script does not output any time just showing minutes and seconds. The logic is changed. Please help in solving.  thank you

Comment: then the only thing to do is this. Step 1: Before the `foreach` loop, place this statement: `$retval = ""`. Step 2: Change the `=` back to `.=`. Let me know how it goes.